# Using 'caveat' as adverb to introduce a sentence

Tags: adverbs, adverb-position

I would like to use *caveat* to introduce a sentence where I specify important information. For example:

*You can wash mostly anything in this washing machine. **Caveat**, if you wash wool set the temperature under 30 degrees Celsius*.

*You can drink from the bottles in the fridge. **Caveat**, put the cap back on the soda bottles*.

Is that standard English or does it sound weird?

Comment: It sounds weird. :)

Comment: It would sound better if you replaced the comma with a colon.

Comment: It only really fits the first sentence. A caveat is something you need to look out for, such as making sure the temperature is correct. For the bottle cap it would be more normal to say _Please put the cap back on the bottle_. If you don't, there wouldn't be any consequences like your laundry shrinking.

Comment: @OliverMason actually I wrote "soda" bottles, because if you do not put the cap, the drink is not sparkling any more. So there is also a negative consequence. ;)

Comment: @loved.by.Jesus But you already had your drink by then... :)

Comment: Caveatly, this is all anxietizing me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[*Caveat*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/caveat) is a countable noun and you need an article in front of it. That's why your phrasing sounds strange. With a bit of rewriting, however, you can still put *caveat* at the start of a sentence.

> You can wash mostly anything in this washing machine. *A caveat is that* if you wash wool, set the temperature under 30 degrees Celsius.

If you are trying to use it as a kind of warning, a more traditional approach is to put it in the middle of a sentence—or to use something different.

> You can wash mostly anything in this washing machine but *with the caveat that* if you wash wool, set the temperature under 30 degrees Celsius.
>
> You can wash mostly anything in this washing machine.
> **Note**: If you wash wool, set the temperature under 30 degrees Celsius.

(In the second example, both *caution* and *warning* can also be used, depending on severity and styling.)